# Click on a point and perform a geoprocessing tool?

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk

In ArcMap, I have created a Python Add-In tool that clicks on a point anywhere on the map, then uses the coordinates as an input to a geoprocessing tool that runs a select by location and buffer of various other parameters. It works very well and also will add and remove data from the map.

I am looking to recreate this tool in ArcGIS pro. Is there a way that I can do something like this without having to make some sort of AddIn? I have heard FeatureSet may do something like this. I can change up the words in the Geoprocessing tool to match the ArcGIS pro language, however, am stumped with being able to click on the map to get an input without having to do some sort of Visual Studio SDK ArcGIS pro workaround.

Comment: If you want an example, the script tool here makes use of input featuresets: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=efacb13eced948b6b006079f13fb9b0b (makeBallDiamondtool.py and the associated tbx)

Comment: I believe python addins do not yet exist in Arcgis Pro, suggest you vote it up [here](https://community.esri.com/ideas/10509-python-add-ins-for-arcgis-pro).

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @KHibma:

> If you want an example, the script tool here makes use of input
>   featuresets:
>   http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=efacb13eced948b6b006079f13fb9b0b
>   (makeBallDiamondtool.py and the associated tbx)

Comment: @KHibma I checked this out and while this seems relevant, I don't think it is quite what I'm looking for. I want a tool that the user can click on a point and then grab that point as an input to a tool. Seems only to be possible through add-ins unless I were to make each individual point feature into a feature. Correct me if I'm wrong though.